# Android WebView in RecyclerView NullPointer

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

So I have an app that should show JSON fetched url in a WebView that is coded in Activity that opens on a RecyclerView item click.

On the **Activity** where RecyclerView is I've wroten this:

```
JSONObject stranica = jsonObject.getJSONObject("artist");
                        String webStranica = stranica.getString("url");

Informacije info = new Informacije();
 info.setWebStranicaArtista(webStranica);
informacije.add(info);
```

Where `Informacije` is a class where all my setters and getters are coded.

I've coded the **Adapter** like this:

```
WebView webStranica;

 webStranica = (WebView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.webViewStranicaArtista);
```

Those 2 lines are inside `ViewHolder` class, and in `onBindViewHolder` I have this:

```
holder.webStranica.loadUrl(data.get(position).getWebStranicaArtista());
```

Where `data` is an `ArrayList` of `Informacije` explained earlier.

And finally in **DetailsActivity** I have this:

```
webStranica.loadUrl(informacije.getWebStranicaArtista());
```

And all I get is a **NullPoinerException** that points to this line:

```
holder.webStranica.loadUrl(data.get(position).getWebStranicaArtista());
```

in Adapter class.

What did I do wrong?

ADAPTER FULL CODE:

```
public class RecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecAdapter.RecHolder>{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Informacije> data;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public RecAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Informacije> data, LayoutInflater inflater){
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public RecHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        RecHolder holder = new RecHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bandImage.setImageUrl(data.get(position).getUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.artistName.setText(data.get(position).getArtist());
        holder.songName.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.informacije = data.get(position);
        holder.webStranica.loadUrl(data.get(position).getWebStranicaArtista());
        Log.i("ok rec", "ok recycler");

        final RecHolder finalRecHolder = holder;

        holder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Details.class);
                Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                mBundle.putSerializable("eventObj", finalRecHolder.informacije);
                i.putExtras(mBundle);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class RecHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView artistName, songName, listeners, duration;
        Informacije informacije;
        NetworkImageView bandImage;
        RelativeLayout container;
        WebView webStranica;

        public RecHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            bandImage = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSlikaNaListi);
            artistName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewImeBenda);
            songName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewImePjesme);
            duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDuration);
            listeners = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewListeners);
            container = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
            webStranica = (WebView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.webViewStranicaArtista);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: StackTrace and activity. please.

Comment: Output your logs at 1. data 2. data.get(position) 3. data.get(position).getWebStranicaArtista() 4. WebStanica to see what's the null one.

Comment: The null is in the Adapter class

Comment: Adapter code is in the first post

Comment: you have to check the line number of the NullPointerException

Comment: I did and I wroten that in first post, the line is holder.webStranica.loadUrl(data.get(position).getWebStranicaArtista()); inside Adapter class